# Android: What's wrong with this VideoView?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, video-streaming

I'm working on an application for Android using Eclipse. I want to stream a video from the internet in my app. I have read a lot of the questions and answers from here and got far but the video is not playing!

I get this message when I call the video:

> Cannot play video.... Sorry, this video cannot be played.

Here is a copy of the code I'm using in XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<VideoView android:id="@+id/tvvideoView"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</VideoView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is the Java code:

```
package appinventor.ai_ignacioleon7.ElSalvadorTVRadioGuide;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;


public class Tvdiplay1 extends Activity {
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         setContentView(R.layout.tvdisplay);

         VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.tvvideoView);
         MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
         mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
         Uri video = Uri.parse("http://www.ustream.tv/channel/5474055");
         videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
         videoView.setVideoURI(video);
         videoView.start();
    }
}
```

Am I using the wrong Uri address? Or can videos from websites like ustream, livestream or justin.tv not be played in the VideoView?

Other videos I want to be able to display in my app will be from http://www.livestream.com/canal33sv

But I'm getting the same error!

Comment: did you find a way to stream from USTREAM?

Comment: @Lunatikul no I didn't ending making a webview from where I show a webpage that has the player inside (inside my website to not show the ustream website)

Answer (score 2):

This is a web page address, not a video URI. If the videos can be played or not, it depends (on what player is it for, for example) but you need to give the actual path of the video, not of the site.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but how do I get the video URI for this specific sites I want to stream?

Comment: I'm not sure that's the best way, but I investigate the source code of the page.